# Ubuntu Laravel : permission denied when i write/read file in external hdd

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

Right now I'm developing an application in Laravel.
I have to write and read files to and from an external hard drive to the pc.

It keeps giving me the following error

[image]

`

```
Route::get("test",function () {
   file_put_contents(storage_path("app")."/public/pippo_correttamente.txt","Hi!");
   die;
});
```

`

The storage/app folder permissions are as follows:

[image]

The storage/app/public link permissions are as follows:

[image]

The permission of external hdd are as follows:

[image]

Why don't run ?

Comment: Please copy the error messages and permissions into code blocks and remove the images. Images can not be searched so they will be less useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, You can use `chmod -R 0777` to set the permission of Storage device

Comment: Your solution is not correct.